# Mailchimp API: remove existing tags from member is impossible

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp-api-v3.0

after reading many posts with the same problem and after trying many different ways to resolve my problem I hope to find here the solution with your help

I want to remove a tag from a member in Mailchimp but when I do it by API in the WordPress function the response code is 204

```
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

$api     = 'my_api';
$list_id = 'id_list';

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$email        = $current_user->user_email;

$response = wp_remote_post( 
    'https://'. substr( $api, strpos( $api, '-') + 1 ) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id  . '/members/' . md5( strtolower( $email ) ) . '/tags', 
    array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user:'. $api )
        ),
        'tags' => array(['name'=>'gomme','status'=>'inactive'])
    )
);

error_log( 'gform_after_submission: response => ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
```

in the official documentation https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-member-tags/ -> Add or remove member tags, explain there is the possibility to update/remove but no user in every post I read did success

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimps API works, I use this code to add and remove tags:

Using Mailchimps official [PHP SDK](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php)

```
$data = [
    'tags' => [
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'status' => 'active'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Test22',
            'status' => 'inactive'
        ]
    ]
];

$this->apiClient->lists->updateListMemberTags('abcdeg123', 'mail@example.com', $data);
```

You have to follow the exact array structure, otherwise the api will not add or remove the tags. It is somewhat odd that there is no error coming from the api when sending an incorrect data structure. It will only report malformed JSON.